# Configurar vários domínios em portas diferentes no mesmo servidor

Tags: servidor, domínio

Tenho um servidor VPS que está rodando com um servidor Apache (porta 80), um servidor Tomcat (porta 8090) e um Wildfly na porta 8080.

Mas eu queria saber se existe uma forma de configurar um domínio para cada porta, por exemplo: Meu servidor tem o ip `x.x.x.x`, quando o usuário entrar em `dominio1.com.br` ele será redirecionado para esse ip (na porta 80 claro), quando ele entrar em `dominio2.com.br` ele será redirecionado para porta `x.x.x.x:8090` e quando ele tentar entrar em `dominio3.com.br` ele seria redirecionado para o wildfly na porta 8080.

Será que dá pra fazer isso? Vi que tem como fazer algo parecido com Virtual Host do apache, só que ele só redireciona entre diretórios mas não entre portas...

Comment: Acho que isso vai te ajudar ["How to redirect DNS to different ports"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015138/how-to-redirect-dns-to-different-ports)

Comment: @RodrigoBorth, não entendi muito bem... em `name` eu coloco o que? Meu domínio principal? E em `Target` (que no caso do meu CPanel é `Hostname`) eu ponho o domínio para o qual eu queira redirecionar?

Comment: pesquise um pouco mais sobre SRV Records, eu nunca precisei fazer isso então não tenho certeza de como te ajudar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure seu Apache para responder pelos três domínios, cada qual com seu Virtual Host, direcionado cada um para um diretório específico.

Em cada diretório, crie um arquivo .htaccess com as seguintes especificações:

1) .htaccess para domínio1:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domminio1.com.br$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.dominio1.com.br$
RewriteRule ^.*$ "http\:\/\/x\.x\.x\.x\:80%{REQUEST_URI}" [P,QSA,L]
```

2) .htaccess para domínio2:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dominio2.com.br$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.dominio2.com.br$
RewriteRule ^.*$ "http\:\/\/x\.x\.x\.x\:8090%{REQUEST_URI}" [P,QSA,L]
```

3) .htaccess para domínio3:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domminio3.com.br$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.dominio3.com.br$
RewriteRule ^.*$ "http\:\/\/x\.x\.x\.x\:8080%{REQUEST_URI}" [P,QSA,L]
```

Caso haja alguma dificuldade, informe qual a versão do seu Apache.